# DS installation error

Tags: datastage

im trying to install DS server and im getting the following error

FAILED: CDIPR2079I: Ensure that user xmeta_user can connect to the database  on host  at port number  and has create table, create view, create index, and create trigger rights. Resolution: Ensure that user xmeta_user can connect to database  on host  at port number  and has create table, create view, create index, and create trigger rights.

Can you please let me know what i have to do?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please see these tech notes:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21606320

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21514883

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.